# Different clusters Spark Structured Streaming from delta file on cluster A to cluster B

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I am trying to stream a delta table from cluster A to Cluster B, but I am not able to load or write data to a different cluster:

```
streamingDf = spark.readStream.format("delta").option("ignoreChanges", "true") \
              .load("hdfs://cluster_A/delta-table")

stream = streamingDf.writeStream.format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")\
         .start("hdfs://cluster_B/delta-sink")
```

Then, I get the following error: 
**org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block**

So, my question is if it is posiible to stream data directly from two clusters using delta format, or additional technologies are requiered to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was related to firewall rules, all the nodes in cluster A must have access to all the nodes in cluster B with the corresponding ports. I had only set the ports on the namenodes

Answer (score 0):

It is supported.
Refer https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#write-a-stream-of-data-to-a-table

Exception you are facing seems to be due to some issue with NameNode and Data Nodes in your hdfs/delta lake cluster.
Refer https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/solved-mystery-blockmissingexception-hadoop-file-system-rajat-kumar

Comment: Everything in the documentation is within the same cluster, I can not see if it is possible to share information between clusters using this delta streaming, I think a technology like Kafka is needed

Comment: There is nothing to indicate it should be within the same cluster. As long as both clusters are reachable from spark cluster it should be possible. https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html. Example here too indicates you can have 2 different clusters as url as long as both are reachable from your spark cluster